# How to split backslash from backslash notation in Python 3

Tags: python

This is my word that I need to split out to list but unfortunately my word start with `t` it look like backslash notation `\t -> (Tab)`

```
animal = "\\tiger\tortoise\tropicbird"
animals = animal.split('\\')
print(animals)
```

output

```
['', 'tiger\tortoise\tropicbird']
```

Expect

```
['', 'tiger','tortoise','tropicbird']
```

Dose anyone have experience like this. How should i do. ?

Thanks

Comment: If you wanted actual t's in your string, you should not have written `"\\tiger\tortoise\tropicbird"`. Only the first t is a real t there; the others are part of `\t` escape sequences, representing tabs.

Comment: The correct way to deal with this depends on where your strings are coming from. If they're all hardcoded string literals, you need to escape them properly; the escape sequence for a backslash is two backslashes. If they're coming from user input or a web request or a file or something, then escape sequence processing will not occur, and you will not actually have the problem you're seeing (but you'll probably think you have a problem if you inspect the `repr` of the input and see a bunch of extra backslashes you don't understand).

Comment: @user2357112 I agree with you, I should redesign the input

Comment: There are quite a lot of different ways to do this.
However, one thing first: Be very careful when using backslashes in non-raw strings.
So, I wanted to ask: Is the backslash here simply a separation character? And, if so, why is it a backslash?

Comment: @1313e Yes, at the first design we define a backslash to separate the word by forgot about backslash notation. right now we already redesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is used as an escape character. As mentioned by user2357112, in your animal variable, the only real t is the t in the word "tiger".

What you should do is modify your animal variable from

`animal = "\\tiger\tortoise\tropicbird"`
to `animal = "\\tiger\\tortoise\\tropicbird"`

You can do this by:
`animal = animal.replace('\t', '\\t')`

and then `animals = animal.split('\\')` will give you the expected answer.

```
>>> animal = "\\tiger\tortoise\tropicbird"
>>> animal = animal.replace('\t', '\\t')
>>> animal
'\\tiger\\tortoise\\tropicbird'
>>> animals = animal.split('\\')
>>> animals
['', 'tiger', 'tortoise', 'tropicbird']
```

Comment: I would first replace all escaped backslashes (or whatever is used as a separator) by spaces, and then simply use `animals = animal.split()`. This will return a list where empty entries have automatically been removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
animal = r"\\tiger\tortoise\tropicbird"
```

instead. Pay attention to the `r`, that makes the `\` literal.